# 2sxc 9.10 Cannot assign method group to an implicitly-typed local variable

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have a 2sxc app with a list and details view in a Razor template. I have used it on a few site without issue. I normally export the app and import it into the new site and it works fine. However I'm currently getting an error trying to use the app in DNN 8.4 and 2sxc 9.10 when I select the app:

```
Error: System.Web.HttpCompileException (0x80004005): c:\inetpub\vhosts\xxxxxxxxxx.co.nz\httpdocs\Portals\1\2sxc\Projects\_projectsSLS.cshtml(10): error CS0815: Cannot assign method group to an implicitly-typed local variable at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(VirtualPath virtualPath) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(String virtualPath) at ToSic.SexyContent.Engines.RazorEngine.CreateWebPageInstance() in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\2Sexy Content Razor\RazorEngine.cs:line 71 at ToSic.SexyContent.Engines.RazorEngine.InitWebpage() in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\2Sexy Content Razor\RazorEngine.cs:line 106 at ToSic.SexyContent.Engines.RazorEngine.Init() in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\2Sexy Content Razor\RazorEngine.cs:line 26 at ToSic.SexyContent.Engines.EngineBase.Init(Template template, App app, ModuleInfo hostingModule, IDataSource dataSource, InstancePurposes instancePurposes, SxcInstance sxcInstance, Log parentLog) in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\SexyContent\Engines\EngineBase.cs:line 58 at ToSic.SexyContent.SxcInstance.GetRenderingEngine(InstancePurposes renderingPurpose) in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\SexyContent\SxcInstance.cs:line 265 at ToSic.SexyContent.SxcInstance.Render() in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\SexyContent\SxcInstance.cs:line 222
```

This normally just runs. Any advice on what the issue may be?

I get the same error trying to run the Simple Parent/Child App with 2 Pages app.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to a minor breaking change in 9.3 or 9.8. 2sxc 9.14 gives you better error messages so you can fix it yourself, but it basically points you to this blog post: https://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/fixing-the-breaking-change-on-tosic-eav-ientity-in-2sxc-9-3 or this one https://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/fixing-the-breaking-change-in-2sxc-9-8-list-instead-of-dictionary